# Crypto-JS is now missing on google codes

Tags: javascript, google-code, cryptojs

I was using the online version of `Crypto-Js` hosted on `google codes` see below:

```
<script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
```

Then yesterday my website suddenly crashed, and I find out that the host doesn't exist anymore. Am I the only one using this link? Did they move it to a different link?

[image: crypto-js]

Comment: they stopped google code. you need to download it from github. it's funny/cute/scary that you would load crypto code from another server in the first place; you must be very trusting of google because they have earned such a good reputation protecting all our privacy and not rolling over for the NSA on a whimper...

Comment: Lol thanks! Anyways I found it here https://code.google.com/archive/ and downloaded it manually. @dandavis

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are few ways to get the `CryptoJs` codes.

1. Get from the google code archive : [Crypto-Js](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/)
2. CDN : [CryptoJs CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js)

**Note**

This answer might get outdated through time and I cant really track it and this solution might not work in the future, if so, just comment here so I can update it :)

Comment: do you know how do I get a rollup from 4.0.0?

Answer (score 9):

You can use **cloudfare CDN**, they still have the files. Below are the links

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/core-min.js`

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/hmac-sha512.js`

Comment: This one is the exact same which is mentioned in the question. Just rename hmac-sha512.js to hmac-sha256.js

Comment: Thanks for this. Note that the version linked above (3.1.2) is the latest version hosted on Cloudflare. The library on github is now on version 4.x